# Yii2 gridview freeze columns like in excel

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a table with ~30 columns. So I have a vertical scroll and I need the 3-4 columns stay fixed in position like when you use "Freeze Panes" in Excel. Is there anyway to do that in Gridview?

My gridview table:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'headerRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
    'filterRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'employee_id',
        'fullname',
        'gender',
        'birth',
        'birthplace',
        'hometown',
        'address',
        'addressnow',
        'phone',
        'mailcom',
        'mail',
        'skype',
        'cmnd',
        'datecmnd',
        'placecmnd',
        'race',
        'religion',
        'skill',
        'datecom',
        'team',
        'bhxh',
        'datebhxh',
        'placebhxh',
        'emergency',
        'emergencynum',
        'groupmail',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

modify your code to be like this

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
         'rowOptions' => function ($model) {
            //add your condition here
            if ($model->id == 1 || $model->id == 2 || $model->id == 3  ) {
                  return ['style' => ' position:fixed;'];
            }
          },
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'headerRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
        'filterRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
        'columns' => [
            'id',
            'employee_id',
            'fullname',
            'gender',
            'birth',
            'birthplace',
            'hometown',
            'address',
            'addressnow',
            'phone',
            'mailcom',
            'mail',
            'skype',
            'cmnd',
            'datecmnd',
            'placecmnd',
            'race',
            'religion',
            'skill',
            'datecom',
            'team',
            'bhxh',
            'datebhxh',
            'placebhxh',
            'emergency',
            'emergencynum',
            'groupmail',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: That will freeze 3 rows in best scenario.

Comment: no I have just gave him an example about that ; in reality he could give the style or the class he want for the rows that he want by changing the condition above.

Comment: i've tried your method, but I need to freeze columns, not rows, can you help me with that? thank you